# get dropdown values into an array on change event using jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I get the dropdown values into an array. I want to get the dropdowns values on change of the dropdown. I am iterating through the dropdowns and on change of the dropdown, I need to get the value of each dropdown to be stored in an array. Later point of time, I need to get this array values to do other operations. I checked jquery map, but that doesnt help to solve my problem.
How is it possible? Can somebody help me?

Comment: share your code which u tried !!!!

Comment: @rynhe In this fiddle, I need to get value of month and year dropdown and store it in an array..Then i can use that array values to do other operations...http://jsfiddle.net/e9zxY/25/

Comment: u want to get the selected value as array rite ?

Comment: are you want to get the values attribute? you can get it by '$(this).attr("value")'

Comment: @rynhe..yes I want the selected values of the 2 dropdowns into the array..

Comment: check my answer ... see your browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
var arrayOfValues = new Array();
$(".bookDetails select").each(function(i,obj){
    $(obj).change(function() {
         $(".bookDetails select").each(function(i,obj){
            arrayOfValues.push($(obj).find(":selected").val());         
         });
        console.log(arrayOfValues);
    });
});
```

Comment: live demo (http://jsfiddle.net/e9zxY/32/)